# iPad SDK for 2D graphics and gui elements?

Tags: iphone, ipad, graphics, sdk, 2d

Im looking for some sort of SDK or library on top of iOS, which might help me produce iPad/IPHONE games.

The sort of functionality Im looking for is..

- GUI elements, skinnable buttons, lists, dialog boxes etc
- Any routines to help with tile based games
- Functions to paint and move sprites
- Any vector libs to help with rotation, skew etc

Im confident I could write all this from scratch, but Im guessing theres some libraries already out there. Im not afraid of getting my hands dirty in code, so please dont slate me for asking for prebuilt stuff :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defacto answer is [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/). Open source, MIT licensed, sprite library (including tiling map support baked in).

As for UI - Cocos has some helper utilities for dealing with UI elements, however its not very hard to skin UIKit (though the more customization you do the more drawing code you end up with).

Answer (score 2):

most of the bits are already available in UIKit, but http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/ is a framework worth looking at for game dev.

Answer (score 0):

Two notes about cocos-2d:
- cocos has its own implementation of UI control called MenuItem. It can be used to easily emulate the behaviors of Buttons. There is also a simple layout algorithm to dispose this items in columns, rows, grids. There are also other controls that allow you to display text on the screen (labels). No text editors though, AFAIK.
- cocos can be easily integrated with the rest of UIKit, so it is simple to show standard "message boxes", some UIKit elements on top or behind it. I was able to use the cocos view as the child view of a UIImagePicker, for example.